# Probability of an infinite subsequence in a randomly generated sequence of order type $\omega_1$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Given for example $\omega_1$ coin tosses (i.e. a mapping from the elements of $\omega_1$ to $\{H,T\}$ with independent probabilities half), what is the probability that there is an infinite <del>subsequence</del> subinterval [*corrected following comments*] consisting only of heads?

Is this question even well defined? Does it depend on the set theory axiomatisation?

For a countable sequence of tosses (i.e. $<\omega_1$) the answer is presumably zero, as an infinite subinterval of heads is as likely as any of the uncountably many other possible infinite subintervals.

Comment: There is a well-defined probability measure on $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$, thanks to Kolmogorov's extension theorem. I don't think that "having an infinite subsequence of 1" will define a measurable subset, though (if only because $\omega_1$ has uncountably many such subsequences). It might be possible to circumvent this difficulty (showing that a bigger set is measurable and has measure 0, for instance), but I somehow doubt it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "an infinite subsequence"?  Your final paragraph makes it sound like you don't have the standard meaning in mind.

Comment: @PseudoNeo: It is not hard to show that that set is not Borel (essentially, any Borel set can only depend on countably many of the coin tosses).  However, Brent's answer shows that it in fact contains a Borel set of measure 1.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I think you misinterpreted the last paragraph. He's saying that if $C$ contains only 0s on an infinite interval $I \subset \alpha$, then, for every sequence $\sigma$ in $\{0, 1\}^I$, you get a "parallel" subset $C_\sigma$ where the sequences now show $\sigma$ in restriction to $I$. Now, all these subspaces $(C_\sigma)$ should intuitively have the same measure, and as there are many of them, $0$ is the only possibility...

Comment: @EricWofsey: OK, I agree with you if "infinite subsequence" means "image of a map $\omega \to \omega_1$. But I interpreted it as "an infinite interval of $\omega_1$", where Brent's argument doesn't work. So: you're definitely right, the OP should clarify what he means :-)

Comment: @PseudoNeo: sorry for the confusion. I was indeed thinking of images of $\omega$ in the last paragraph. Though since every infinite interval contains such an image as a subinterval doesn't the argument that the probability is 0 carry over to arbitrary subsequences?

Comment: @PseudoNeo: I think I'm still being confused and/or confusing. I definitely mean an interval, not just an arbitrary subset. My argument in the third paragraph concerned intervals of order type $\omega$ but in general I'm interested in any interval.

Comment: If there is an infinite interval, then there is an infinite interval of order type $\omega$. So it really suffices to consider the case of $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  Just so you know, the standard meaning of "subsequence" is an arbitrary subset (or maybe an arbitrary unbounded subset), not just a subinterval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking "subsequence" to mean "subinterval", the set you are describing is not measurable, and in fact has outer measure $1$ and inner measure $0$.  Indeed, let $S\subset\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$ be the set of sequences which are constant with value $1$ on some infinite interval in $\omega_1$.  Suppose $B\subset S$ is a Borel set.  Then there is some $\alpha<\omega_1$ and some $A\subseteq \{0,1\}^\alpha$ such that $B=A\times\{0,1\}^{[\alpha,\omega_1)}$.  It is then clear that every element of $A$ must be constant with value $1$ on some infinite interval in $\alpha$. There are only countably many such infinite intervals, and the set of sequences that are constant on each one has measure zero.  So $A$ must have measure zero, and hence $B$ has measure zero.  This shows $\omega_1$ has inner measure zero.

Now suppose $B\supset S$ is Borel, and let $B=A\times\{0,1\}^{[\alpha,\omega_1)}$ as before.  An element of $S$ can have any restriction to $\alpha$ (since its infinite interval of $1$s could come after $\alpha$), so $A$ must be all of $\{0,1\}^\alpha$.  Thus $B=\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$ and has measure 1.  Hence $S$ has outer measure $1$.

Since the inner measure and outer measure of $S$ do not agree, $S$ is not measurable.  That is, the probability of the event you are describing happening is undefined, at least for the standard definition of "probability".

Answer (score 2):

In reference to the countable sequence of tosses, the probability of any individual subsequence might be zero, but that is not the same as the probability of there *existing* an infinite subsequence of heads.  The only way to *not* have an infinite subsequence of heads is if, after some finite point, you only get tails from then on.  Now, the probability of getting only tails from then on would be 0, and so the probability of its complement, equivalent to the probability of there being a subsequence of heads, would be $1-0=1$.

Considering that same logic, I would imagine the answer would be the same for $\omega_1$ tosses...although I can't quite wrap my head around uncountably many discrete events like coin tosses.

Comment: Note that the OP is talking about coin tosses indexed by a countable ordinal (which might very well be $\neq \omega$). In this situation, having an infinite sequence of heads isn't the same thing as having eventually only heads. For instance, on the ordinal $\omega \cdot 2 = \omega + \omega$, having heads for all $\alpha < \omega$ and then anything you want gives you an infinite subsequence of heads...

Comment: Yes, applying this argument to any countably infinite subset of $\omega_1$ gives that the set of sequences with no infinite subsequence of heads is contained in a set of measure zero and hence has measure zero itself.

Comment: You're right, I misread Brent's answer. *Mea culpa*.